# Extract all instances of a substring in an array column and move to a new column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I am fairly new to python so please bare with me. I am attempting to extract all instances of a specific substring between two markers and export it to a new column. The file contains thousands of columns, sometimes with hundreds of rows for the column (['INFO']) that I'm interested in. Specifically, I want to extract the string that always follows "|HIGH|" as shown in the example below.

```
**#CHROM    POS ALT INFO
217 1   21351411    <DEL>   SVTYPE=DEL;STRANDS=+-:25;SVLEN=-18597;END=21370008;CIPOS=-10,652;CIEND=-236,9;CIPOS95=-1,104;CIEND95=-48,2;IMPRECISE;SU=25;PE=25;SR=0;ANN=<DEL>|transcript_ablation|HIGH|Khdc1c|Khdc1c|transcript|NM_001033904.1|protein_coding|1/3|c.-17246_*281del|p.0?|||||,<DEL>|splice_region_variant&downstream_gene_variant|LOW|Khdc1a|Khdc1a|transcript|NM_183322.2|protein_coding|3/3|c.*319_*18915del|||||0|,<DEL>|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|Khdc1a|Khdc1a|transcript|NM_183322.2|protein_coding|3/3|c.*319_*18915del|||||319|,<DEL>|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|Khdc1c|Khdc1c|transcript|NM_001033904.1|protein_coding|1/3|c.-17246_*281del|||||16919|,<DEL>|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|Khdc1c|Khdc1c|transcript|NM_001033904.1|protein_coding|1/3|c.-17246_*281del|||||0|,<DEL>|intergenic_region|MODIFIER|Khdc1a-Khdc1c|Khdc1a-Khdc1c|intergenic_region|Khdc1a-Khdc1c|||n.21351412_21370008del||||||,<DEL>|intergenic_region|MODIFIER|Khdc1c-Khdc1b|Khdc1c-Khdc1b|intergenic_region|Khdc1c-Khdc1b|||n.21351412_21370008del||||||,**
```

Each of the lines I'm interested in for the ['INFO'] column contains "...|HIGH|Gene_here|".
There can be hundreds of these lines in a given row and I want all of the substring instances for a given line to be exported to one new column but kept in the same row. I just want the gene name that follows "|HIGH|" but ends before the next "|" to be extracted to the new column in all instances.

I have attempted to do this with a for loop using regex but can't quite figure it out.

```
import re
for substring in df['INFO']:
    df = df['INFO']
    pattern = "HIGH\|(\w+)\|"
    substring = re.search(pattern, df).group(1)
    df['GENE'] = susbtring
```

Comment: Maybe you should parse your string with appropriate tools. Have a look at BioPython.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you were using the `for` loop there, but to perform the operation you stated I would write code as follows.

```
for frame in df:
   keyWord = '|HIGH|'
   tempString = str(df[frame]['INFO'])
   index = tempString.find(keyWord)
   rIndex = tempString.find('|',index+len(keyWord))
   df[frame]['GENE'] = tempString[index+len(keyWord):rIndex]
```

Comment: When I try to run this code, I get an attribute error saying that 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'. I tried using new code I made '''df['GENE'] = df.INFO.str.extractall('HIGH|(\w+)|')''' but I think python wants to put each new word into a separate row, as I get the error "TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index" which leads to "ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'". Is there a way to concatenate all substrings from one row to stay in the same row in the new column?